# Для каждой строки найти номер первой пары неравных элементов. Данные записать в новый массив. Python

Tags: python

Помогите, пожалуйста, несколько дней уже не могу решить эту достаточно лёгкую задачу:
"**Дан массив n*n, элементы которого целые числа.
Для каждой строки найти номер первой пары неравных элементов. Данные записать в новый массив.**"
Я ещё новичок в программировании и знаю пока что только основы, поэтому прошу не бить палками если буду тупить отвечая на вопросы)
У меня есть предположения, что эта задача выполняется через функцию, а как - **я не знаю.**
P.S. Нужно писать на **Python**.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите по этой [ссылке](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/224707624), вроде ответ на вопрос есть:

[image: Взял c mail.ru]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Я указал фотографию, это и есть самое главное

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 фотография кода — это одна из самых ужасных вещей, такой код нельзя ни скопировать, ни найти поиском